# How to track google analytics event in a flutter widget?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-analytics

I am looking to track how many times a button/expansion tile is clicked.

I tried reading the docs but still can't get the concept of it. In the flutter fire docs, it stated to log custom events by calling the logEvent method [hERE](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/analytics/usage/).

```
await FirebaseAnalytics.instance
  .logEvent(
    name: 'view_product',
    parameters: {
      'product_id': 1234,
    }
  );
```

However, what if it is an expansion tile widget (like the code below) or even a button? How do I track the event whenever a user pressed the expansion tile widget/button in flutter and the event will be tracked in my Google Analytics? (I have already set up firebase and google analytics packages, just struggling on the code part)

```
ExpansionTile(
                title: RichText(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                  text: TextSpan(
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                      TextSpan(
                        text: "Diploma in Business | ",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: "Taylor\u0027s",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Appreciate any help or guidance I can get, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make your ExpansionTile clickable. Wrap your ExpansionTile with Inkwell and its onTap property call logevent function

```
Inkwell(
 onTap:(){
   sendAnalyticsEvent("User clicked expansionTile");
},
child : ExpansionTile(
 //write your expansion tile
 ),
);
```

And this the analytics custom event function.

```
 final FirebaseAnalytics _analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
 Future sendAnalyticsEvent(
     {String eventName, String? clickevent}) async {
      await _analytics.logEvent(
      name: '${eventName}',
      parameters: <String, dynamic>{
        'clickEvent': clickevent
     },
   );
 }
```

Call this function like this

`sendAnalyticsEvent( eventName : "expansionTile_one", clickevent : "User clicked first expansionTile")`

`sendAnalyticsEvent( eventName : "expansionTile_two", clickevent : "User clicked 2nd expansionTile")`

Check this click event in analytics debugView.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I tried with the code, it works, but not quite right. I have clicked the expansiontile many times but GA is only showing one time even after refreshing the page.

Is there smthg wrong?

Comment: It worked fine for me. Though I dont know if it can detect quick clicks or not. You need to wait a little to get it logged. Or you can integrate Google Tag Manager with GA, which works well in button clicks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It works fine! Sorry, another quick question, if I have like more than 10 expansiontiles to track, how can I make the event function to track each and every one of them, instead of rewriting the whole function?

Comment: Pass the event name as parameter in sendAnalyticsEvent function. I have edited my code. Please check

Comment: Firebae analytics dosent have a unnamed constructor

Answer (score 0):

Inside your ExpansionTile, you can use:

```
onExpansionChanged: (value){
    sendAnalyticsEvent("User clicked expansionTile");
}
```